# how do i implement a database and how do i appropriately link each button

Tags: mysql, database, xcode

My app involves implementing data and displaying it to the user.i'll give you a full explanation of the app and what i'm trying to achieve.

Basically the app finds out what car is best suited for the user. last week i decided that a drop down menu will be easier and more interactive than a normal questionnaire. i have three labels, performance, luxury, eco friendly and three buttons, high performance, high luxury and high eco friendly. how can i add data to these so that when the user picks these preferences, it links to a specific car, let me remind you that this is just one of many controllers and questions.

I read that MYSQL is good  but I'm not sure if its easier or harder. To be honest, im still in beginner level for programming. Also some linking  and database videos on youtube are a joke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to get you more on track. Your question shows that you're a newbie but if you're a newbie with some sense you'll catch on instead of complain.

MySQL is a variant of SQL. Unfortunately Oracle (evil Microsoft of the business world--think vendor lock-in) bought out Sun Microsystems (a not evil corporation that should have been defended to the death or close-to). There is some political concern that MySQL is slowly being closed off in favor of Oracle so if you have the option opt for PostgreSQL.

With a database you have two things: a database and a user.

The database part is easy, that is where information is stored.

The user part is still pretty easy, different users have different permissions. Those permissions in example are what SQL commands can be executed.

A database's structure is basically....

Database --> Table --> Columns/Rows

A database table is like an HTML table, columns are sets of data (a 'name' column, an 'address' column, etc). Each row is an entry. Bob's information may be on row 34, Sally's information on row 35, etc.

The four most common commands you'll use: `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `DELETE` and `UPDATE`. With my software unless a webmaster is signed in a lower level privileged SQL user only has access to these four base SQL commands.

There are two contexts to working with SQL: building it and using it. I'm not an expert though what I've generally accepted is that *using* SQL across different variants (e.g. MySQL and PostgreSQL) for day-to-day use (accessing, updating, removing, editing data) utilizes standardized SQL commands. Sure, some companies may change the structure of their database on a daily or even hourly basis ON a regular basis but generally speaking not everyone. Commands to change a database structure such as `ALTER` may NOT be cross-variant standard. Why does this matter? If you don't understand the politics of what is involved then YOU DO NOT UNDERSTAND WHAT IS INVOLVED. So I've made sure I'll be able to easily migrate from MySQL to PostgreSQL by avoiding vendor specific syntax. Spend an extra 20% doing things right the first time and you'll save 80% of the time wasted on maintenance by everyone else.

If you want jump in and start using MySQL get a copy of [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html). It takes minimal effort and is great for LOCAL testing (local means YOUR computer only accessible to you/your LAN, live means available on the web in general). I'm not sure about xcode but the general instructions should at least give you a basic guide to stay on track in regards to databases.

If you're looking to learn with a GUI you'll want to use phpMyAdmin (included with XAMPP) though I don't recommend downloading the latest copy as they're going way overboard with some things in phpMyAdmin. PostgreSQL has it's equivalent. It'll show you working (albeit VERY messy) examples of commands. For your reference here are some commands I use in the console...

The highest privileged user in SQL is usually called 'root' (without quotes). You'll have root access on your localhost (local) and dedicated servers (likely VPS too) though not on shared servers unless you're some kind of 1337 haxorz.

---

The four most common commands...

Using `SELECT` to retrieve data...

```
SELECT * FROM database_table;

SELECT id, name FROM database_table WHERE cool_factor='exact matching text';
```

Using `DELETE` to remove a record...

```
DELETE FROM database_table WHERE id='1';
```

Using `INSERT` to add a single new record...

```
INSERT INTO email_filters (age, name) VALUES ('Bob');
```

Using `INSERT` to add multiple new records...

```
INSERT INTO email_filters (name) VALUES ('Bob','23'), ('Sally','24'), ('Susan','25'), ('Irate Yeti','9001');
```

Using `UPDATE` to update an existing record...

```
UPDATE accounts SET name='Mr. Yeti', profession='eating people' WHERE id='234';
```

BTW it's common practice to make your syntax uppercase to differentiate between SOL-specific syntax and your content.

---

Important commands that help you create and get around in SQL...m

Login: this will prompt you for a password...

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

Show a list of databases (phpMyAdmin will let you create databases)...

```
show databases;
```

Select a database to work with...

```
USE mysql;
```

Select an SQL user...

```
SELECT User FROM user;
SELECT User FROM mysql.user;
```

Create a user (with a normal and admin example)...

```
CREATE USER 'example_v10'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_!1337_p@ss';
CREATE USER 'example_v10a'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_!1337_p@ss';
```

Before an SQL user can access a database it must be granted permission, here is a limited permission example...

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON `example_mysite_database`.* TO 'example_v10'@'localhost';
```

...and an administrative user being granted all permissions (use with caution)...

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `example_mysite_database`.* TO 'example_v10a'@'localhost';
```

Import an SQL file in to an existing database...

```
SOURCE C:\path1\path2\the.sql
```

Describe a database...

```
DESCRIBE table_name;
```

Change an SQL user's password...

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('lulz_bad_password');
```

It's VERY important to realize in the long run that you'll be COMPOSING SQL queries, you NEVER dump them in a loop. Your goal is to make larger more elegant SQL queries that do more in fewer queries if not a single query whenever possible. In example a typical page request on my site's software utilizes about eight~12 queries subjective to the section/page/permissions/etc. Poorly written software like WordPress will utilize dozens if not more requests.

You will absolutely not be able to do anything effectively with databases without learning how to do RELATIONAL SQL; that is just fancy way of saying you know how to use `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` (and some people use `OUTER JOIN`). A `JOIN` allows you to store a piece of information in the entire database once, like an account name. If you build a forum and want to pull forum posts you would JOIN the user accounts table and simply pull the user names by dynamically referencing them, you wouldn't actually store their user name every single time. However that is for another day. I learned SQL over a couple months and once I learned relational SQL I exploded making a blog in three weeks, a forum in a month, a chat room in three weeks, etc.

Feel free to use this as a cheat-sheet and give you some sense in how to reference some technical jargon. when you ask questions you need to be as concise and accurate with terminology as possible. Asking extremely large questions (how can I make a facebook without doing any work?) is bad, asking a specific question is good (How do I have my programming language connect to a database with a specific user that has limited privileges?)

Comment: i so needed that explanation, thank you and i will use it as a cheat sheet.However, say i don use PostgreSQL or XAMPP there is no other way of adding data  in Xcode because I've seen parent entity and attribute. although it depends on the scale of the data and the project.

Comment: Glad to help. You can just use XAMPP and MySQL standalone until you get used to xcode if you're having trouble with xcode. While writing code (such as PHP) along with MySQL would enable you to build something you can use just using phpMyAdmin and messing with the database directly will let you concentrate on getting comfortable with SQL.